# Ansible pipe lookup to generate encrypted password using interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

I am trying to use Ansible's pipe lookup plugin to generate an encrypted string. In below task, "admin_password" is one of the variable in my hostvars file

```
- name: Encrypt password
  set_fact: passwd="{{ lookup('pipe', 'python3 -c \"import crypt; print(crypt.crypt(\" {{admin_password}}\", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))\"') }}*"
```

Upon running this task, I get the following error

> An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'pipe'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>,t.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))") returned 1

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never nest Jinja `{{...}}` template markers. You're already inside a template context; you don't need them.

First, I'd like to suggest an alternate solution to your question:
just use Ansible's [`password_hash`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#encrypting-and-checksumming-strings-and-passwords) filter:

```
set_fact:
  passwd: "{{ admin_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

Or as a runnable playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    admin_password: mypassword
  tasks:
    - name: Encrypt password
      set_fact:
        passwd: "{{ admin_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"

    - debug:
        var: passwd
```

---

That said, if you want to interpolate a variable into a string, you
have a few options.

You can use the `~` string concatenation operator:

```
"some string " ~ myvariable ~ " the rest of the string"
```

You can use Python's `%` operator:

```
"some string %s the rest of the string" % (myvariable,)
```

You can use the string `.format` method:

```
"some string {} the rest of the string".format(myvariable)
```

So for what you're trying to do, you could write:

```
- name: Encrypt password
  set_fact:
    passwd: >-
      {{
      lookup('pipe',
      'python3 -c "import crypt; print(crypt.crypt(\"%s\",
      crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))"' % admin_password)
      }}*
```

In addition to the string formatting, I've made one other change here:
I'm using YAML's folded block operator (`>`) to (a) remove one level
of quoting, so we don't need to escape quite so many quotes, and (b)
to make it easier to format things for better readability.

Here's a runnable test:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    admin_password: mypassword
  tasks:
    - name: Encrypt password
      set_fact:
        passwd: >-
          {{
          lookup('pipe',
          'python3 -c "import crypt; print(crypt.crypt(\"%s\",
          crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))"' % admin_password)
          }}*

    - debug:
        var: passwd
```